# How does an int arithmetic result equal true in an if statement with no equals?

Tags: php, if-statement

I am mainly a c# programmer and I am currently trying to convert some php code with no php knowledge. I have successfully converted what I needed except for this one if statement.

It doesn't seem similar to any if statement that I have used in java,c++ or c# and my googling has been fruitless.

What is this actually doing?

```
if ($var1["string1"][$var2]["string2"] - $var3["string2"])
```

Comment: Can you post the actual line, this one has syntax errors in it.

Comment: It depends on the contents of the variables. The end result of this will be an integer, but depending on the values it could be anything.

Comment: For more information check: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: I fixed the code. I'm not concerned about the result so much, just unsure of what was happening. What is happening in the first part of the equation, I am assuming that it is 2 variables being added together? eg. if((int+int)- int > 0) in c#?

Comment: the first is a multi array. its the value of $var1[key1][key2][key3], so just a single value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `$var1["string1"][$var2]["string2"]`
is a three dimensional associative array like `var1[0][1][2]` in Java, but here the indexes are Strings instead of integers as is the case with associative arrays.

And `$var2` (value of `$var2` must come from somewhere else) is used as an index for the second dimension of the array, like `"string1"` is used as index for first dimension.

Rest is simple, you are subtracting two elements, if result is 0 then it will be false else it will be true.

Comment: This is the complete answer I was after. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

An arithmetic expression will result in something that's either `0` or not `0`. `0` evaluates to `false`, everything else won't.

Comment: Cheers, this is exactly what I needed to know!

Answer (score 1):

Check (the summary) of this page, it shows an overview of what is true/false in php.

http://11heavens.com/true-or-false-in-php

In your case it will return a number and any number in PHP is true, except for 0 and 0.0